# Is there a way to get notified before / after Software Installation

Tags: c#, .net, windows

It is possible to get a list of installed software, i know.

But i want to write a tool that gets notified before / after the user installs software on his PC.

Is that possible ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have already stated you can get a list of software installed. You can use this same information to determine whether something has changed and run this on a periodic basis.

Comment: Yes but is there a way to get notified on installation, not after ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) it will raise event when there is an activity with files or folder.

Comment: Yes but, again, is there a way to get notified on installation, not after ?